# Include paths for nvcc on windows

Tags: windows, mingw, include-path, nvcc

I'm trying to compile a CUDA C code in Windows command line. I've already installed cuda toolkit and `nvcc` works fine. But the code includes `png.h` and I'd like to know what is the proper way to provide it.

Specifically, I want to learn what are the default directories in which nvcc looks for headers and `.dll`s. And how should I install such standard C libraries: do I necessarily have to use MinGW and somehow add `C:\MinGW\include` and `C:\MinGW\bin` to the `PATH`?

Currently my solution looks in the following way:

```
$ nvcc mandelbrot-dynamic.cu -O3 -arch=sm_35 -rdc=true -lcudadevrt -Xcompiler -fopenmp -Ic:/mingw/include/ -o dynamic
```

And the result is:

```
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-fopenmp' mandelbrot-dynamic.cu 
c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin/amd64/../../../VC/INCLUDE\yvals.h(472) : warning C4005: '_EXTERN_C' : macro redefinition
    c:/mingw/include/_mingw.h(258) : see previous definition of '_EXTERN_C'
c:/mingw/include/float.h(38) : fatal error C1021: invalid preprocessor command 'include_next'
```

It doesn't complain about `png.h` but there is conflict between MSVC and MingW. Plus, nvcc doesn't accept a preprocessor command from a mingw header.

Comment: you can only use `nvcc` with MSVC on windows; did you read the documentation? http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#file-and-path-specifications

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But I didn't get about MSVC: I looked in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include` and didn't find `png.h` there. You mean I should use some MS Visual Studio functionality instead of libpng for creating `png` images?

Comment: you need to install libpng, e.g. from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libpng.htm or compile it yourself

Comment: I did it. Still: when compile with `--pre-include c:/mingw/include/png.h` it reports that no such file. When compile with `-Ic:/mingw/include/` the conflict described in question takes place.